# Metal texture sampler - How to get the value of a texel?

Tags: textures, metal

I try to understand what coord would return the value of a particular texel when using a Metal texture sampler. For a 1D texture, does sampling the texture at 0.5 return the exact value of the first texel (whether the filtering is nearest or linear)?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing what kind of sampler you are using.

Comment: What I mean is, if your sampler has `coord::normalized`, 0.5 is just the middle of the texture.

Comment: Yes, you right! I meant when sampler has coord::pixel.

Comment: Then yes, the center of a pixel is at n + 0.5

Comment: But, to be clear, I think if you need a texel, you shouldn't be sampling. You should be reading.  Because, for mipmapped textures you are not going to get a texel, depending on the sampler, you are gonna get an interpolation.